# SQlite - запрос с фильтрами

Tags: sql, sqlite

Мне необходимо получить только записи, которые соответствуют определённым параметрам.
Например, таблица имеет столбцы **number** и **word**. Мне необходимо получить записи, где number равен 14 или 17 и т. д.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE number IN (14, 17)
```

Также нужно получить только записи, где в столбце word есть не менее одного из фрагментов текста ("абв", "где"). Это для примера. Список может быть другим и содержать любые значения. Как можно это осуществить?

Answer (score 0):

Для работы со строками есть регулярные выражения.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE word REGEXP '\b(абв|где)\b';
```

- `\b` обозначает границу слова.
- `|` обозначает логическое `или`.
- `^` начало строки. Например, `^abc` выдаст все строки, которые начинаются на `abc`.
- `$` конец строки. Например, `abc$` выдаст все строки, которые заканчиваются на `abc`.
- `\d` или `[0-9]`  обозначает множество цифр.
- `\w` или `[a-zA-Z0-9]` обозначает множество символов образующих слова.
- `.` обозначает любой символ
- `*` или `{0,}` обозначает повторение символа от ноля до бесконечности раз.
- `+` или `{1,}` обозначает повторение символа от одного до бесконечности раз.
- `?` или `{0,1}` обозначает повторение символа от ноля до одного раз, то есть другими словами необязательность символа: может быть, может не быть.

Например, `[0-9]{4,}` будет выбирать строки, где есть число минимум из 4х цифр. `\b[0-9]{4}\b` будет выбирать строки, где есть число точно из 4х цифр. `\b[0-9]{1,4}\b`  будет выбирать строки, где есть число из от 1й до 4х цифр. `\b(20)?\d{2}\b` будет соответствовать строкам `2000`, `2011`, `2099` и `00`, `11`, `99`, но не будет соответствовать `1900`, `1911`, `1999`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться строковым функциями CHARINDEX и PATINDEX

например так, если таблица не очень большая:

```
SELECT * FROM Table charindex("абв", word)>0 or charindex("где", word)>0
```

либо так:

```
SELECT * FROM Table charindex("абв", word)>0
union
SELECT * FROM Table charindex("где", word)>0
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]